# how to draw rotated part of the canvas in D-7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am drawing something on an A3 printer canvas.

Is it possible to copy the part of the canvas and 
draw rotated (180degree) in another part of the canvas?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you'd be better off abstracting out the drawing code into a routine and then drawing twice, once unrotated and once again but rotated.

Comment: There are lots of lines, texts. That's the reason why I thought it would be nice if I could rotate it by 180degree

Comment: Why didn't you say you wanted the rotation to be 180°?!  That's so much easier than a general rotation!

Comment: huh, sorry .., so How can I rotate the content of my printer.canvas, is it possible?

Comment: There's `SetLayout`, but it doesn't rotate 180°, it rather draws the mirror image. I think you have to draw twice, once by using `SetWorldTransform` ...

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Will it transform all primitives(lines,rectangulars,texts) on my canvas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like Sertac commented already, use [`SetWorldTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145104%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  XForm: TXForm;
begin
  if PrintDialog1.Execute then
    with Printer do
    begin
      BeginDoc;
      SetGraphicsMode(Canvas.Handle, GM_ADVANCED);
      PrintTo(Canvas);
      XForm.eM11 := Cos(DegToRad(180));
      XForm.eM12 := Sin(DegToRad(180));
      XForm.eM21 := -Sin(DegToRad(180));
      XForm.eM22 := Cos(DegToRad(180));
      XForm.eDx := PageWidth;
      XForm.eDy := PageHeight;
      SetWorldTransform(Canvas.Handle, XForm);
      PrintTo(Canvas);
      EndDoc;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.PrintTo(ACanvas: TCanvas);
begin
  with ACanvas do
  begin
    Font.Size := 180;
    TextOut(0, 0, 'Test text');
    Pen.Width := 40;
    MoveTo(0, 0);
    LineTo(3000, 3000);
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this function. But I have a question. According to msdn I should call: SetGraphicsMode (Fcanvas.Handle, GM_ADVANCED); prior to use World transformation. But then all mess up. Also the mirror reflection is a little moved in relation to the base picture, however I have applied the correct page size settings. ..

Comment: It doesn't mess up here. Maybe the device capabilities of your printer driver do not support the advanced graphics mode? I added your code to my answer though, because you áre right.

Answer (score 0):

You could paint the *repetitive part* to a temporary bitmap, and draw that bitmap twice on the printer's canvas, once rotated. The rotation could be done for instance with [PlgBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162804%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
procedure RotateBitmap180(Source, Dest: TBitmap);
var
  Points: array[0..2] of TPoint;
begin
  if (Source <> nil) and (Dest <> nil) then
    with Source, Canvas do
    begin
      Dest.Width := Width;
      Dest.Height := Height;
      Points[0].X := Width - 1;
      Points[0].Y := Height - 1;
      Points[1].X := -1;
      Points[1].Y := Height - 1;
      Points[2].X := Width - 1;
      Points[2].Y := -1;
      PlgBlt(Dest.Canvas.Handle, Points, Handle, 0, 0, Width, Height, 0, 0, 0);
      Dest.Modified := True;
    end;
end;
```

Note: there are way more efficient rotation routines available, since PlgBlt not only rotates but also scales. But this short one does the job.